# cannot find symbol Integer.parseDouble java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class MyClass   
{
    BufferedReader BR=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    double[][] input() throws IOException
    {
            int col = 3;
            int row = 3;
            int size = 0;
            String m;
            double[][] scores=new double[row][col];
            System.out.println("Enter your scores: ");
            int i = 0;
            while(i < scores.length)
            {
                int j = 0;
                while(j < scores[i].length)
                {
                    m=BR.readLine();
                    scores[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(m);

                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
        return scores;
    }
    double[] average(double[][] a)
    {
        double[] avg =new double[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            double average=0;
            double value=0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
            {
                value = a[i][j];
                average += value;           
            }
            avg[i]=average/3;
        }
        return avg;
    }
    void display(double[] avg)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("The average of row ",i," is %.2f",avg[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        MyClass obj=new MyClass();
        obj.display(obj.average(obj.input()));
    }
}
```

the code gives an error saying,

> unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
>           obj.display(obj.average(obj.input()));

Help me out with this code please. the code takes input of 3x3 matrix elements and display the average of three rows. can you help to get a working code?

Comment: what does the javadoc say?

Comment: And do you find it logical to have a method parsing a **double** into the class **Integer**?

Comment: Use a good IDE and you will get help with situations like this automatically

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans IDE can find your error before you compile and run...

```
try
{
    MyClass obj=new MyClass();
    obj.display(obj.average(obj.input()));

} catch (IOException ex)
{
    Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```